# Nodejs Script fs.createReadStream to Python Script

Tags: python, node.js, file

I need to convert a file to readable stream to upload through api, there is a node js example which uses **fs.createReadStream**. Can any body tell me what is python equivalent of the aforesaid statement ?

example

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const FormData = require('form-data');

export const pinFileToIPFS = (pinataApiKey, pinataSecretApiKey) => {
    const url = `https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS`;

    //we gather a local file for this example, but any valid readStream source will work here.
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', fs.createReadStream('./yourfile.png'));
```

How can i replicate above in pythonic way?

Answer (score 1):

[`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#open) in Python does what `fs.createReadStream()` does in **Node.JS**.