# How to send stream data using just python?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, web-development-server

I am currently learning NodeJS and I learned a really neat way of sending big files, using streams, I already have a bit of an experience with Django but how can I do the following in Django (or python)

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')

const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    const fileContent = fs.createReadStream('./content/bigFile.txt', 'utf8')
    fileContent.on('open', ()=>{
        fileContent.pipe(res)
    })
    fileContent.on('error',(err)=>res.end(err) )
})
    

server.listen(5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use open like this

```
f = open("myfile", "rb")
try:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != "":
        # Do stuff with byte.
        byte = f.read(1)
finally:
    f.close()
```

Or if is an image you could you use this

```
from io import StringIO # "import StringIO" directly in python2
from PIL import Image
im1 = Image.open(IMAGE_FILE)

# here, we create an empty string buffer    
buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
im1.save(buffer, "JPEG", quality=10)

# ... do something else ...

# write the buffer to a file to make sure it worked
with open("./photo-quality10.jpg", "w") as handle:
    handle.write(buffer.contents())
```

References

- [How to perform JPEG compression in Python without writing/reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771652/how-to-perform-jpeg-compression-in-python-without-writing-reading)
- [Nodejs Script fs.createReadStream to Python Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58387569/nodejs-script-fs-createreadstream-to-python-script)